# only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, complex-numbers

How I can change that code for running? It is necessary to run graphic that produces a function `w(omega) = 1/(1 + 1j*omega)` on the real and imaginary axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def func(a):
    for x in range(len(a)):
        plt.plot([0, a[x].real], [0, a[x].imag], 'ro-', label='python')
    limit=np.max(np.ceil(np.absolute(a))) # set limits for axis
    plt.xlim((-limit,limit))
    plt.ylim((-limit,limit))
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
    plt.xlabel('Real')
    plt.show()

omega = np.linspace(-4, 4, 251)
a = np.arange(1) + 1j*np.arange(omega, 1)  
func(a)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just write `a = 1/(1 + 1j*omega)`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: the error arises from the fact that `omega` is an array, but `arange` expects scalar arguments: the from-to-step values. Since it gets a length-1 array (`omega`), it can't determine which value of `omega` it should choose as the starting point of the range. Hence the error: `omega` cannot be converted to a scalar (which would make `arange` work).

But it's still unclear why you're exactly plotting this way, and exactly what you want to put in the array `a`.